# Cohomology Groups, Coefficient Groups, and Modules

Tags: algebraic-topology, modules, homology-cohomology

Two simple things that I am unable to find any good reference on by googling...

First, I wanted to be able to prove that given a space $X$, and a ring $R$, then the cohomology groups $H^{i}(X;R)$ were all necessarily $R$-modules. This should be a standard proof, but I cannot find it anywhere.

However, when looking for said such proof, I came across this line on Wikipedia:

> In what follows, the coefficient group $A$ is sometimes not written. It is common to take $A$ to be a commutative ring $R$; then the cohomology groups are $R$-modules.

And that greatly confused me, as to why $H^{i} (X,R)$ need not be an $R$-module if $R$ is non-commutative.

Any references, hints, and full explanations are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking primarily about the case that $R$ is noncommutative ring? I can come up with a lot of references for the commutative case...

Comment: I'm asking about both. Though I certainly think I'd be closer to understanding the non-commutative case if I understood the commutative case. So, by all means, give me your references! :)

Comment: It's because there are problems at the Hom-level if $R$ is non-commutative.  Do you know when $\mathrm{Hom}_R(A,B)$ is an $R$-module?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but some googling seems to indicate that it is necessarily the case when $R$ is commutative.

Comment: For the commutative case, I believe that Spanier's "Algebraic Topology" covers the module point of view carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think that I've figured this one out, but I could use someone to either give it their stamp of approval, or their stamp of disapproval.

Let's, for simplicity's sake, say that we are looking at simplicial cohomology. Then we have a cochain complex
$$
\dots \leftarrow C^{n+1} (X) \leftarrow C^{n} (X) \leftarrow C^{n-1} (X) \leftarrow \dots \leftarrow C^1 (X) \leftarrow C^0 (X) \leftarrow 0 .
$$
where $C^i (X) = \text{Hom}(C_i (X),R)$. Then, we can render $C^{i} (X)$ an $R$-module by defining an action $\cdot : R \times C^i (X) \rightarrow C^i (X)$ by $r \cdot \varphi=r \varphi$. Both kernels and images are submodules, this means that the induced action on $H^{i} (X,R) = \ker (C^{i} \rightarrow C^{i+1})/\text{im} (C^{i-1} \rightarrow C^{i})$ is well-defined.

The problem is that if $R$ is not commutative, then we don't necessarily have that the arrows are $R$-linear. Specifically, it is not a given that $r \cdot \delta (\varphi) = \delta (r \cdot \varphi)$.

Is that understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s it.  Also, the hom set might not even be a module to begin with.